# Лексико-грамматические ошибки в предложении

Tags: лексика, грамматика

Есть ли в этом предложении лексико-грамматические ошибки?

*Войска освободителей встречали тысячи жителей города.*

Answer (score 1):

Правильно:  ***Тысячи жителей** города встречали **войска освободителей**.*

Здесь нежелательна инверсия подлежащего и дополнения, так как их формы (И.п. и В.п) совпадают. В результате неясно, кто кого встречал.

**Правило Розенталя:** 180. МЕСТО ДОПОЛНЕНИЯ В ПРЕДЛОЖЕНИИ

3. **Прямое дополнение,** совпадающее по форме с подлежащим, ставится, как правило, **после сказуемого**, например: Мать любит дочь; Весло задело платье; Лень порождает беспечность; Суды защищают законы. При перестановке подлежащего и дополнения меняется смысл предложения (Дочь любит мать; Платье задело весло) или возникает **двусмысленность** (Беспечность порождает лень; Законы защищают суды). Иногда в подобных случаях инверсии сохраняется нужный смысл, вытекающий из лексического значения названных членов предложения (Велосипед разбил трамвай; Солнце закрыло облако), но правильное понимание таких предложений несколько затрудняется, поэтому рекомендуется или сохранять прямой порядок слов, или действительный оборот заменять страдательным (Велосипед разбит трамваем; Солнце закрыто облаком).

Источник: http://rus-yaz.niv.ru/doc/rules-rosental/articles/180-mesto-dopolneniya-v-predlozhenii.htm